# How prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2006}}<a_{2006}<\frac{2}{\sqrt{2006}}$ in sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_{n}\}_{n=0}$ be defined recursively by $a_{0}=\pi/4$, and $a_{n+1}=\sin a_{n}$ for $n=0,1,\ldots$. How prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2006}}<a_{2006}<\frac{2}{\sqrt{2006}}$?

Comment: What is the value of $a_0$?

Comment: This is non-trivial enough so that I will not vote to close. You still should list some of the available tools. What course does this exercise come from? Have you covered Taylor series of sine?...

Comment: the value of $a_0=\frac{1}{4}\pi$

Comment: yes, covered Taylor series of sine

Comment: For $x \in \left( 0, \sqrt{3} \right)$ we have $x^2 - \frac{x^4}{3} \le \sin^2 x \le x^2 - \frac{x^4}{3} + \frac{2}{45} x^6$, and what about this?

Comment: But you could have searched the site also. See [this related answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/45285/11619) to get an idea of what this entails. That does use Taylor series (and may be only heuristic), but there are alternatives. Anyway, you need to estimate the difference between $x$ and $\sin x$, when $x$ is relatively small. See how that compares with similar difference for $f(x)=1/\sqrt x$ and $2/\sqrt x$. Or if that doesn't work, then you need to ask someone else for advice :-)

Comment: Looks like that (or something similar) will be helpful here. Try it out!

Comment: My suggestion is to check whether you can prove the inequalities
$$a_n<\frac2{\sqrt n}$$ and $$\frac1{\sqrt n}<a_n$$ by induction using the inequality that you were given in the inductive step. Remember that sine is an increasing function in a relevant interval. As is square root. The inductive step may only work for a range of values of $n$, so I don't know what would be a good base case for the two inductions.

Comment: ok will try to solve